# "not until" and "only" - which part of the sentence is inverted and why?

Tags: grammar, inversion, negative-inversion

In one of my grammar books, there are two examples how to use "not until" and "only" in a sentence:

> 1. **Not until the next day did I hear** that I had got the job.
> 2. **Only at the end of the interview did I think** I had a chance of getting the job.

But there is also a note that *with "not" and "only", you have to be careful about which verb to invert* with the following examples:

> 3. **Not until I had finished** my homework **was I allowed** to go out.
> 4. **Only when I had finished** my homework **was I allowed** to go out.

In such a case, why in the examples 1 and 2 the first verb phrase (did I hear, did I think) is inverted and not the second one (I had got the job, I had a chance)?

Comment: In #3 and #4, "until I had finished" is syntactically the same as "until the next day" (or just "until then") in terms of how that part relates to the entire sentence containing that "reference to a point in time". Any subject/verb inversion only applies to the ***main*** clause *(did I hear, did I think, was I allowed)*.

Comment: Compare *Only now **s/he has read the comment** IS ANIA able to understand this.* Where without "only", there is no inversion: *Now s/he has read the comment, ANIA IS able to understand this.*

Comment: In these examples, it's the main clause that contains the inversion.

Answer (score 1):

I add to what @FumbleFingers and @Billy Kerr said.
Any subject-auxiliary inversion applies only to the main clause.

British Council has similar examples in its
[***Only* + time expression**](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/c1-grammar/inversion-after-negative-adverbials#:%7E:text=To%20invert%20a%20sentence%20in,they%20talked%20throughout%20the%20film.) section:

> Only when they refilled my glass *did I realise* it was broken.

> Only later *did they discover* they hadn't been told the truth.

Inversion applies only to the main clause; the subordinate declarative content clauses are not inverted.